# rich components are not displayed properly

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

I'm using RichFaces 4.5.2 and when I run my server the rich components are not displayed properly.

For example, for the code:

```
    <rich:inputNumberSlider value="50" />
```

I should have gotten the following result:

[image: wanted result]

and instead, this is what I see:

[image]

Related JARs:
cssparser-0.9.14.jar, guava-18.0.jar,richfaces-a4j-4.5.2.jar, richfaces-core-4.5.2.jar, richfaces-page-fragments-4.5.2.jar, richfaces-rich-4.5.2.jar, sac-1.3.jar.

Why does it happen?
Thanks.

Comment: Didn't you see the following warning in the server log? *"One or more resources has the target of 'head' but not 'head' component has been defined within the view"*

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is using the h:head tag instead of a simple head tag.